# Как выбрать отмеченную кнопку RadioButton.Checked?

Tags: c#

Доброго времени суток. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с синтаксисом С#. Имеется 4 radioButton, одна из них выбрана. Как выбрать эту выбранную кнопку? Что-то типа RadioButton.Checked. Вопрос нубский, ну и я пока нуб. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Установка в позицию выбрана:

```
radioButton.Checked = true;
```

Проверка если выбрана:

```
if(radioButton.Checked){...}
```

RadioButton объединяются в группы - когда может быть выбран только один, тогда чтобы узнать какой именно выбрал пользователь, необходимо проверять каждый по очереди до тех пор пока не найдете выбранный.

Answer (score 4):

```
for (int i = 0; i < radioButton.count; i++) {
    if (radioButton[i].Checked) {
        MessegeBox.Show("Нашлась красавица");
    }
}
```

Comment: зашибись, спасибо чувак)